# ten years use VS. ten years of use

Tags: prepositions

which of these two sentences is correct?

> This product will stand up to ten years use.
>
> This product will stand up to ten years of use.

In addition, I cannot understand the meaning of the following:

> ten years use.
>
> ten years of use.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either is correct. They both mean that the product will last, even after being used, for ten years.

Comment: Though note that there should be an apostrophe after "years" for the first case, as it is possessive: ten years' use.

Comment: what a bout this version?the use of ten years

Comment: And, is your points applied for these? a ten years old boy

Comment: No, not in American English. We would say "a ten-year-old boy".

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answers to this post that both expressions are valid. A Google Ngram comparing the two shows that "X years of use" is more common, by an order of magnitude, than "X years use."

Comment: I would upvote this answer if it provided a screen grab of the Ngram, or a link.